# Function would not return value, instead it returns "None"

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, return

Please help me look at this piece of code which was supposed to calculate the greatest common division between two numbers `(a, b)`. The problem I'm having is that the program would not return `c` as expected, instead it return `None`. But when I use a `print` statement, it prints out the value of `c`.

This is my code:

```
def gcd(a, b):
    if a == 0:
        return b
    elif b == 0:
        return a

    elif a > b:
        big, small = a, b
    else:
        big, small = b, a

    c = big % small
    if c == 0:
        print(small)
        return small
    gcd(small, c)

print(gcd(1071, 462))
```

Thanks guys.

Comment: Well you forgot a `return` on the last line. `return gcd(small, c)`.

Comment: I assume this is an exercise and you realise that Python has `math.gcd` already included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python implicitly returns `None` when no explicit `return` is encountered and the function body ends.

In your case if it passes through all other cases it just hits:

```
gcd(small, c)
return None    # you haven't put that in explicitly but that's how Python processes it
```

So you probably just need to change the last line to:

```
return gcd(small, c)
```

Comment: Thank you so very much. I was thinking the return inside the "if" statement would do.